# Я хочу перенести пол строчки на другую строчку, чтобы текст вмещался. Как мне это исполнить?

Tags: python, discord

Код:

```
@bot.command()
async def drake(ctx, *, text):
if len(text) > 45:
    return await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(title='Произошла ошибка!',         description=f'<:error:852403860765016097> {ctx.author.mention} ваш текст больше 45     символов!!',color=error))

text = text.split(";")
text2 = text[0]
text3 = text[1]
img = Image.open("drake.jpg")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
drawer = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
font = ImageFont.truetype("9303.ttf", 48)
drawer.text((355, 150), text=text2, fill='black',font=font)
draw.text((342, 470), text=text3,fill='black',font=font)
img.save("drake2.jpg")
img.paste(img, (7, 5))
await ctx.send(file = discord.File("drake2.jpg"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Для этого используется символ переноса строки: `'\n'`

Пример:

```
print('Hello' + '\n' + 'world!')
```

Вывод:

```
Hello
world!
```

Автоматизация:

```
import re

text = "Мой дядя самых честных правил Мой дядя самых честных правил"
text = re.split('[., ]+', text)
txt = ''

for i in range(len(text)):
    if (i/8).is_integer() and i/8!=0:
        txt = txt + '\n'
    txt = txt + ' ' + text[i]
print(txt)
```

Вывод:

```
 Мой дядя самых честных правил Мой дядя самых
 честных правил
```

Comment: Подозреваю, что он имел автоматический перенос текста на основе ширины, а не ручную вставку перевода строки в нужное место.

Comment: Думаю ему это поможет (см. ответ)

Comment: Ну это всё равно не по ширине текста, а просто в 2 строки, да ещё и потенциально с разрывом внутри слова. К тому же, буквы бывают разной ширины, например, ШШШ и iii занимают по 3 символа, а первый в 3 раза шире.

Comment: Последнее очень сложно сделать, но первое попробую

Comment: Думаю это уже похоже на ТЗ. Там вывод по 8 слов, и как по мне это оптимально